# difference between bash variable

Tags: bash

I have 2 bash scripts. One is calling another.

Caller.sh

```
arg1="+hcpu_extra=111 bbb"
str="-y +hcpu_extra=111 bbb"

local cmd_re="(-y)(.*)"

if [[ $str =~ $cmd_re ]]
then
  opt=${BASH_REMATCH[1]}
  arg=${BASH_REMATCH[2]}
  echo "matched $opt"
  echo "matched $arg"
fi


./callee.sh -y $arg
 ## ./callee.sh -y $arg1
```

I found if I print $arg1 and $arg, they show the same value "+hcpu_extra=111 bbb" on the screen. But when I pass them respectively to the callee.sh as the argument. I got different results . **So my question is , what is the difference between $arg and $arg1 from bash interpreter's point of view? .**

Comment: And what are the different results that you get in callee.sh? I assume you mean you do `echo $2` in `callee.sh`

Comment: $arg starts with a space, no?

Answer (score 0):

First, the code won't work right as posted, because `local` can't be used except in a function.

If you remove the `local` or put this in a function, the only difference between `arg` and `arg1` is that `arg` starts with a space (the one that was between "-y" and "+hcpu". but since you're expanding those variables without double-quotes around them, that'll be removed... unless you changed `IFS` to something that doesn't contain a space.

(BTW, variable references without double-quotes and changes to IFS are both things that can have weird effects, and are best avoided when possible.)

Anyway, my summary is: the posted code doesn't show the effect you've described; you appear to have left out something important. See [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: You are right. The code snippet was from inside a function.

Double-quotes is not always a good choice to go.